# UIWebView clear cache only if necessary

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

How to delete `UIWebView` cache only if necessary, e.g. when response status code is 304? I use:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

from `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to get status code from the response:

```
int code = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];
```

But the code is always 200 (OK). How to get code 304 (not changed) to know when I need to clear cache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How to get code 304.but code is always 200 (OK)

I don't understand your question - it is the server that sends http codes, are you asking how to change the server so that it sends 304?

Regardless of that, what is the connection between your UIWebView and the NSURLConnection.
Are you using a NSURLConnection inside of shouldStartLoadWithRequest: for some reason?

Comment: Server send 304 code, but NSURLResponse always show code 200. I resolved my problem, instead of checking status code from the response, I use cache policy NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData when I load URL in UIWebView: [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];